# Check if product is in an attribute set by its ID

Tags: product, magento2.3, attribute-set

I want to get Attribute set ID in product page
Can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

**create GetAttributes.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeManagementInterface;

class GetAttributes
{
    /**
     * @var ProductAttributeManagementInterface
     */
    private $productAttributeManagement;

    public function __construct(
        ProductAttributeManagementInterface $productAttributeManagement
    ) {
        $this->productAttributeManagement = $productAttributeManagement;
    }

    /**
     * Get Product Attributes from the attribute set.
     *
     * @return ProductAttributeInterface[]
     */
    public function getAttributeListBySetId()
    {
        $attributeSetId = 4; // Default Attribute set
        try {
            $getAttributes = $this->productAttributeManagement
                ->getAttributes($attributeSetId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $exception) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__($exception->getMessage()));
        }

        return $getAttributes;
    }
}
```

Now just call that collection  where ever you want
Hope this helps

**Update:-**

****this is the way you can call that methods****

```
$getAttributes = $this->getAttributeListBySetId();
foreach ($getAttribute as $attribute){
    var_dump($attribute->debug());
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, Can you take a look please!

Comment: product listing page??

Comment: product page as I mentionned plz

Comment: check updated ans

Comment: Where can I add this file plz

Comment: in your custom module Vendor\Module\Model;

Comment: this custom module will only contain this file? sorry I'm new on module creation

Comment: follow this link to learn about custom module in magento 2 https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

Comment: Thank you very much for your support

Comment: How can I call this collection on phtml file plz

Comment: check updatd ans

Comment: So this custom modum allows me to  get Attribute set ID in product page for example?